# Sum count of a specific value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-bi

I am trying to get the total count for a specific `"COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME"` as it relates to the `"DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE"`.  For example, here is my current query:

```
select "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" as "EQUIP_ONLINE_VALUE" 
 from   "DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"
where  
       "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA_ID" IN (select id from (select "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA".* from "DB"."COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA" "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA",
               "DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT"
where  
       "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."DATA_COLLECTED_TIME" < CURRENT_DATE
   and "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_NO"='1'
   and "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_SITE_ID"="COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"
   and "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_ID"="COMPONENT"."ID"
   and "COMPONENT"."COMPONENT_TYPE_ID" = '123'
   and "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" in ('123ABC')
ORDER BY "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."DATA_COLLECTED_TIME" DESC)
where rownum <= 1)
   and "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" IN (select COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID from (select  "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA".*
from     "DB"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
               "DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA",
               "DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT" 
 where  "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID"="COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"
   and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" ='EquipUp'
   and "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID" = "COMPONENT"."ID"
   and "COMPONENT"."COMPONENT_TYPE_ID" = '123'
   and "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" in ('123ABC')));
```

Current output I believe only shows one count, and not a total sum of all `'EquipUp'`:

```
EQUIP_ONLINE_VALUE                                                                                   
------------------------
1
```

I would like to get a total `'EQUIP_ONLINE_VALUE'` sum of all `'EquipUp'` names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have rownum <=1 on a subquery selecting what looks like and ID (speculating that is unique). Also, I don't see any COUNT( or similar aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

- You do not have a count / sum function in your query.
- Your where clause only returns 1 row, which has a DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA.VALUE
  of 1.
- Are you sure your rownum <= 1 is correct?
- Try running each section in your where clause individually to determine whether they
  bring back multiple rows of data.
- If you require the sum of each
  EquipUp, use a SUM(value) from... group By COMPONENT_DATA_POINT.NAME

Run these 2 scripts to determine you have the correct data to begin with:

```
SELECT "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA".*
        FROM "DB"."COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA" "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"
            ,"DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT"
        WHERE "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."DATA_COLLECTED_TIME" < CURRENT_DATE
            AND "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_NO" = '1'
            AND "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."SITE_UPLOAD_DATA_SITE_ID" = "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"
            AND "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_ID" = "COMPONENT"."ID"
            AND "COMPONENT"."COMPONENT_TYPE_ID" = '123'
            AND "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" IN ('123ABC')
        ORDER BY "COMPONENT_UPLOAD_DATA"."DATA_COLLECTED_TIME" DESC

SELECT "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA".*
        FROM "DB"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"
            ,"DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"
            ,"DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT"
        WHERE "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID" = "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"
            AND "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" = 'EquipUp'
            AND "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID" = "COMPONENT"."ID"
            AND "COMPONENT"."COMPONENT_TYPE_ID" = '123'
            AND "COMPONENT"."SITE_ID" IN ('123ABC')
```

Comment: Janine, would you be so kind as to show me what you mean by this:  

If you require the sum of each EquipUp, use a SUM(value) from... group By COMPONENT_DATA_POINT.NAME

Comment: @Fadiddy please read the following: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp